# How does a hadoop shell command like "hadoop fs -ls" works?

Tags: linux, shell, hadoop

1. I would like to know How does a hadoop shell command like "hadoop fs -ls" be interpreted by hadoop compiler?
2. What happens in the background when I type "hadoop fs -ls /user/hadoop/someDirName"
3. If I want to create my own shell command how do I do it?

Thanks in advance.
I would appreciate if anyone could share links to source code with examples.

Comment: You want to creat your own shell command for Hadoop or your own shell command in general?

Comment: a hadoop shell command.

Answer (score 3):

Every hadoop command internally calls a java utility for the further operations.
`org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell` provide command line access to a FileSystem.

`hadoop fs -ls` internally calls the corresponding method from the above package.

**Note:** `hadoop fs` is deprecated. Now `hdfs dfs` is getting used instead of `hadoop fs`

These links are useful to understand the implementation of it.

[Hadoop File System Utility](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html).

[Hadoop File System Shell Utility](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.collector/1.1.0/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FsShell.java).